# Python tuples regrouping

Tags: python, tuples

I am kind of new to python and currently struggling with returning the list of tuples in a way I want to.

If I have a list of tuples that looks like

```
  [('a',),('b',),('c',),('d',),('e',),('f',)]
```

How can I change it to

```
  [('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f')]
```

or

```
  [('a','b','c'),('d','e'),('f',)] ?
```

Is there an easy way to regroup tuples?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For a *consistent* length of inner tuples, you can flatten your list of tuples via `itertools.chain` and then define a chunking generator:

```
from itertools import chain

L = [('a',),('b',),('c',),('d',),('e',),('f',)]

def chunker(L, n):
    T = tuple(chain.from_iterable(L))
    for i in range(0, len(L), n):
        yield T[i: i+n]

res_2 = list(chunker(L, 2))  # [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
res_3 = list(chunker(L, 3))  # [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]
res_4 = list(chunker(L, 4))  # [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```

Otherwise, you need to first define logic to determine the size of each tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `zip` with appropriate slices:

```
l = [('a',),('b',),('c',),('d',),('e',),('f',)]

[x+y for x, y in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])]
# [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`grouper`** from  [`itertools recipe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

lst = [('a',),('b',),('c',),('d',),('e',),('f',)]

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

**How to use?**

```
>>> list(grouper(2, chain.from_iterable(lst)))
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
>>> list(grouper(3, chain.from_iterable(lst)))
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]
```